# How defining feature "name"-tag to a integer attribute when executing ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I'd like to store a PostgrSQL/PostGIS table as a KML-file with the feature -tag as the value of the integer attribute "count". My procedure works when I point the env.variabe LIBKML_NAME_FIELD to a string attribute but not to a integer attribute.

My procedure:

```
 SET LIBKML_DESCRIPTION_FIELD = OGR_STYLE
 SET LIBKML_NAME_FIELD=count
 ogr2ogr -a_srs epsg:4326 -f "LIBKML" C:\Temp\kml\libkmlobst.kml PG:"dbname='aaa' 
 host='localhost' port='5432' user='xxx' password='yyy'" "obstaclepolygon" -progress'
```

This results in:

```
 <Placemark id="obstaclepolygon1.1">
    <name>{count}</name>
    <description><![CDATA[BRUSH(fc:#FF666633);PEN(c:#66FF66FF,cap:r,w:4);LABEL(f:Verdana,bo:normal,it:normal,c:#0000FFFF,s:18pt,t:{"count"})]]></description>
    <Style>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>ffff0000</color>
      </LabelStyle>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff66ff66</color>
        <width>11.33856</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>336666ff</color>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <ExtendedData>
      <SchemaData schemaUrl="#obstaclepolygon1.schema">
        <SimpleData name="count">9</SimpleData>
      </SchemaData>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
            9.67689802684666,49.7141487124449,0
            9.68097371829448,49.7176729532379,0
            9.68678078417764,49.7190283179581,0
            9.69279142480545,49.718606310807,0
            9.69592786159985,49.7155501486587,0
            9.68792052911842,49.7089878660481,0
            9.67969949573538,49.7096042638657,0
            9.67689802684666,49.7141487124449,0
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
```

when I import the kml into Google Maps, myMap, each feature is listed with the name "{count}".
How do I get it to be named the value of the attribute "count"?

Comment: Try to provide some data for making testing easy. This may work for that purpose `ogr2ogr -a_srs epsg:4326 -f GeoJSON  "C:\Temp\kml\libkmlobst.json"  PG:"dbname='aaa' 
 host='localhost' port='5432' user='xxx' password='yyy'" 
 -sql "select * from obstaclepolygon limit 1"`

Answer (score 0):

use `-fieldTypeToString All` as an argument to ogr2ogr